# getting not a buffer error with express js node

Tags: node.js, express

I am following module p-11(authentication, hashing, curl,etc) and want to do the create user but it's somehow not working.
The problem is that as soon as I am clicking on the submit button
I am getting the not a buffer error. 
not sure what's wrong.

I keep getting the error : TypeError: Not a buffer

I have already required body-parser and crypto.
here's the related code in server.js:

```
function hash(input,salt){
      //how to create hash
      var hashed = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(input,salt, 10000, 512, 'sha512');
      return ['pbkdf2Sync',salt,hashed.toString('hex')].join('$');
     }

    app.post('/create-user',function(req,res){
      //take username and password as input and create entry in user table
      var username = req.body.username;
      var password = req.body.password;
      console.log(username);
      var salt= crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('hex');
      var dbString = hash(password,salt);

      pool.query('INSERT INTO "user"(username,password) VALUES($1,$2)',[username,dbString],function(err,result){
        if(err){
          res.status(500).send(err.toString());

        }else{
          res.send('user succesfully created'+username);
        }
      });
    });

    app.get('/hash/:input',function(req,res){
      var hashString = hash(req.params.input,'this-is-some-random-string');
      res.send(hashString);
    });
```

And here's the related code in main.js

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit_btn');
submitButton.onclick = function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(request.readyState===XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status ===200){
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            console.log(data);
        }
    };

    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    request.open('POST','http://localhost:8080/create-user',true);
    request.send(JSON.stringify({username:username,password:password}));
};
```

Here's the error message I am getting

```
TypeError: Not a buffer
   at TypeError (native)
   at pbkdf2 (crypto.js:562:20)
   at Object.exports.pbkdf2Sync (crypto.js:553:10)
   at hash (D:\imadtw\server.js:119:23)
   at D:\imadtw\server.js:129:18
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\imadtw\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next (D:\imadtw\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (D:\imadtw\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\imadtw\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at D:\imadtw\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
   at Function.process_params (D:\imadtw\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
   at next (D:\imadtw\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
   at jsonParser (D:\imadtw\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:112:7)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\imadtw\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at trim_prefix (D:\imadtw\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
   at D:\imadtw\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
```

EDIT: I just tried something.
the process works okay, when I hard code the values of username and password (just as an experiment), but it doesnt work when I try to get the values of username and password using req.body
seems like getting the values from body is the hard part here.

Here's the html of the page I want input values from

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Fontawesome library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ui/profile.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ui/main.js" ></script>
</head>

<body>
 <!--Navbar Begins    -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top scrolltop" id="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- navbar header begins   -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
 <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Faraz Ahmed</a>

      </div>
      <!-- navbar header ends -->

      <!-- div collapse begins -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#aboutme">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolioz">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contactme">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- div collapse ends -->
    </div>
    <!-- container ends -->
  </nav>
  <!--Navbar ends    -->

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="fullBody">


      <div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="column-main">
        <div id="aboutme" class="about">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div id="img"><img class="img-responsive"  src="http://res.cloudinary.com/whizzy/image/upload/v1454699647/faraz_qwdqrx.jpg" alt=""></div>

         <!-- <hr class="hr1"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><hr class="hr2"> -->

          <p class="aboutpara scrollz"></br>I am a self taught web developer who has learnt html,css, Javascript,Jquery and bootstrap too. I keep building websites and other apps to practice what I have learnt. This site is responsive. Go ahead and take a look at it in your mobile and see how they adjust to your screen size.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- aboutme div ends -->

  <div class="user">

 <p>
  <form method="post" action="/create-user" >
  <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username">
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" class="btn btn-warning">
</form>
 </p>

<ul id="namelist">


</ul>




  </div><!-- requestz div ends -->

<div id='twitterDiv' class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
  <h3>Tweets Here</h3>
  <input type="text" id="tweetSearch" placeholder="enter keyword to search for"></input>
  <button id="tweetButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
<p id="tweetz">tweets appear here</p>

</div><!--column ends -->
</div><!--row ends -->

      </div><!--2nd column ends -->



    </div><!-- main row ends -->





    </div><!-- container-fluid div ends -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which line does the error point to?

Comment: well, I have posted the full error message in my original post.

Comment: Are you sure that `req.body.password` is a string?

Comment: yes, I was putting in a string as the password.

Comment: you may want to show the html...maby something with the doc elements. You could check in the browser console first ?

Comment: okay, I have added the html now. please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're setting the correct body content type:

```
request.open('POST','http://localhost:8080/create-user',true);
request.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
request.send(JSON.stringify({username:username,password:password}));
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. 
could you explain a bit??

Comment: If you don't tell Express (or rather, the `body-parser` middleware) that you're sending it JSON, it will assume that the request data is in URL-encoded format, which isn't the case in your situation.

Comment: if you mean I didnt write the request.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json'); line, then I should tell you that I did write it.

or maybe you mean something else??

Comment: I don't see it written in the code in your question, hence my answer. Also, you may have to `return false` from the function you pass to `submitButton.onclick`, otherwise the form may get submitted.

Comment: oh well.  maybe iIdidn't write it here.  but i had tried this out while experimenting with different things and it still gave the same error

Comment: but I don't understand what you mean by form getting submitted. shouldn't the form be submitted otherwise how will we get the values

Comment: You don't want the actual form to be submitted, that's why you are intercepting the _click_ event of the submit button and sending an XHR request. To prevent the form to be submitted by the browser, you need to cancel the `click` event to prevent the form submission (since you already passed the values with the XHR request).

Comment: aha!  I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

According to your html, you're not setting a `name` attribute for the username field. This means the field won't be sent to the server when the html form is submitted (separately from your XHR).

EDIT: this is probably unrelated to your particular issue with `pbkdf2Sync()` though since it doesn't consider the username value.

Comment: could be.  let me check